# Can i use Microsoft Visual studio Lightswitch 2011 to program WIN32 API?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

i've been trying to do a win32 api programming in Microsoft Visual studio Lightswitch 2011,but the open project explorer shows VB and c#.Is it really possible?

Answer (score 0):

Basically a LightSwitch solution is a 100% Visual Studio solution, by the way there is a number of assemblies specific to Visual Studio LightSwitch that expose namespaces, classes and user controls that can be used only within LightSwitch applications.

This is the main reason why you cannot import the project into Visual Basic. Nevertheless you can write the extensions by using VB:

> Visual Studio LightSwitch is a tool for developing business
>   applications for the desktop, web, and cloud. You can extend the
>   functionality of LightSwitch by creating extensions using Microsoft
>   Visual Studio Professional 2012, the Visual Studio 2012 SDK, and the
>   LightSwitch Extensibility Toolkit for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.

If you want to do a Win32API programming you can take e.g. VS Express for C++ : http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products

Answer (score 0):

The main problem that new people have when starting to program in LightSwitch is expecting to have access to the all of the capabilities of the full .NET Framework.

The *Client Tier*, & the *Middle Tier* are both Silverlight based, & therefore only have access to the functionality that is exposed by Silverlight.

It is possible to trigger a piece of .NET functionality (that will run on the *Server tier*), from the *Client Tier*, but it takes a bit more code to do it, using something like what we call the *Command Table Pattern*.